# Using definition to show that $x^n$ on [0,1] is not uniform convergent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

I know that by continuity transfer property we can show above very easily. But I wanted to it by definition.

My attempt:

Uniform convergence $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ on $E$ means$$\forall \epsilon>0 ,\exists N\in \mathbb N ,\forall x\in E |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon ,\forall n>N.$$

Negation of above statement is $\exists \epsilon>0 ,\forall N\in \mathbb N \exists x\in E \exists n>N |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon $ .
I wanted to use negation to show that $x^n $ is not uniform convergent .

What $\epsilon $ I have to choose so that I get answer?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hint: $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ if and only if: $$\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x) - f(x) | \to 0 \quad \text{ as } n \to \infty$$

Comment: I had One doubts With proving with above hint as $f_n(x)=x^n$ for [0,1) as $n\to \infty $ it is 0 and f(x)=0 for that .ANd at 1 both equal to 1 so difference is 0.And it is not possible to use direct defination to prove above

Comment: This is equivalent to the definition of uniform convergence ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm ).   Moreover, $\sup_{x\in[0,1)} |x^n| = 1 \not\to 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take $\varepsilon=\frac12$, for instance.

If the sequence converged uniformly, then it would converge pointwise. But$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<0\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$So, define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<0\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$

Now, take any $N\in\mathbb N$. If it was true that $(\forall x\in[0,1]):\bigl\lvert x^N-f(x)\bigr\rvert<\frac12$, that would imply that $x^N<\frac12$ if $x\in[0,1)$. But this cannot be true, since $x^N$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and it maps $1$ into $1$. So, by the intermediate value theorem, it cannot jump from $1$ to a number smaller that $\frac12$.

In the previous paragraph, you can avoid any reference to continuity by noting that $\frac1{\sqrt[N]2}\in[0,1]$ and that $\left(\frac1{\sqrt[N]2}\right)^N=\frac12$.